# Json dictionary indexing

Tags: python, json, dictionary, indexing

```
import json
import urllib2
data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(#api_url)
print data
```

This returns something like this:

```
{u'count': 1, u'type': u'UserProfile', u'pagination': {}, u'params': {u'user_id': u'user'}, u'results': [{u'number': 31}]}
```

When I try to do:

```
data["results"]["number"]
```

It returns:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

All I want to do is return "31" and store this data in a variable. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data['results']` is a *list*, *containing* dictionaries:

```
>>> data['results']
[{u'number': 31}]
>>> data['results'][0]
{u'number': 31}
```

Use integer indexing, *then* a string key:

```
data["results"][0]["number"]
```

or loop over `data['results']`; chances are that there could be more than one result with a `number` key:

```
>>> [r['number'] for r in data['results']]
[31]
```

Comment: Ah, that definitely makes sense! Thank you.